# How to filter contours based on their approximate shape in a Binary video frames

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, contour

I'm working on a project where i have to detect a red vehicle (please see image below).

[image: Main image]

As i believe that this can be achieved with out using Deep learning (overkill in this case), i used histogram Back projection depending on the object color(red). The results were satisfying

[image: result]

except when there are objects other than the target red-vehicle having the same color distribution as the target (see example below my T-shirt)  are in the scene, the algorithm thinks it is also an object of interest and thus detect both the object of interest and the irrelevant object (my T-shirt).

[image: second case]

The result are

[image]

In this case, it's easy to only choose the contour that belongs to the car based on ratio and area,since the contour that belongs to the T-shirt is lager and has different ratio

I applied the follwoing example code

```
contours = cv2.findContours(clean, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


area_thresh1 = 500
area_thresh2 = 1000
aspect_thresh1 = 2
aspect_thresh2 = 4
result1 = image.copy()
result2 = image.copy()
for c in contours:

    # get rotated rectangle from contour
    # get its dimensions
    # get angle relative to horizontal from rotated rectangle
    rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rotrect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    (center), (dim1,dim2), angle = rotrect
    maxdim = max(dim1,dim2)
    mindim = min(dim1,dim2)
    area = dim1 * dim2
    if area > 0:
        aspect = maxdim / mindim
        #print(area, aspect)

    if area > area_thresh1 and area < area_thresh2 and aspect > aspect_thresh1 and aspect < 
       aspect_thresh2:
       # draw contour on input
       cv2.drawContours(result1,[c],0,(255,255,255),1)
       # draw rectangle on input
       cv2.drawContours(result2,[box],0,(255,255,255),1)
       print(area, aspect)
```

However, as I'm working on a video, this doesn't work well in some frames since sometimes it detects shapes that fulfill the conditions like the case below
[image: result2]

As you can see in the above binary image, an irrelevant object is detected (the below contour).

**So my question is:**

As you see the red vehicle to be detected always has the same shape (almost rectangle but for sure a convex shape). **So how can i filter only the contour that belongs to the red vehicle using a the shape property ?**(of course I mean a property other than ratio and area since some sopts of my short falls into the same area and ration boundaries of the red vehicle).

**In other words, How can i filter the target object based on the exact shape of the vehicle??**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I suspect that those two shapes are too similar. You may not get a good distinction between them on the basis of shapes. But the best way that I know would be to process your binary mask image by connected components. It permits filtering on a number of metrics related to shape. See skimage.measure.labels at https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.17.x/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label and regionprops at https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.17.x/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops

Comment: You could also use contours and compute various image moments (perhaps the Hu moments) from the contours. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d8/d23/classcv_1_1Moments.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaadc90cb16e2362c9bd6e7363e6e4c317

Comment: What about using the `compactness` of the shape?

Comment: What about compactness? It is just one measure of shape. I do not know if that is the best metric to use for you. You will have to research or try and see how it works. I think you want a metric that indicates rectangularity not circularity.

Comment: You might consider the ratio of area of region / area of rotated bounding box. If that is close to 1, then you have a rectangle. The area of the region is the area of the contour. The area of the rotated bounding box comes from minAreaRect as width*height of the rotated bounding box. You already do those computations. So you only need compute the ratio and filter on that along with possibly area and aspect. You do not need connected components for that.

Comment: You can try( matchShapes) wich  uses Hue moments. and pass those blobs edges with your template edge. I also suggest using Lab  to treshold you'll get a clear rectangular shape.

Comment: Your object has a specific trajectory (i guess). you can create a MASK and search inside it.

Comment: Thanks. Connected components is worth a try@fmw42

Comment: @fmw42. Regarding your suggestion about using HuMoments. I made a small research on it and found out that the first six values of HuMoments are invariant to size, position and orientation for a given shape. That is when the object's shape is constant and doesn't change. In my case the shape of the segmented car is not constant. It is for sure a convex shape which doesn't really help but not always a rectangular. I calculated  7 HuMoments of the red car in a 15 sec Video frame and the first six values were not the same. Does this mean that my understanding is correct ?

Comment: Hu moments for the same shape are invariant (in principle) to scale, rotation and translation. But if your car shape changes, then the moments might vary some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get  shape descriptors and use some kind of rules (or machine learning) to decide if that's the right object you're searching for :

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import sys

target = cv2.imread('YourPath\\target.jpg' , 
cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
mask = cv2.imread('YourPath\\mask.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
SearchImage = cv2.bitwise_and(target,target,mask = mask)

cv2.imshow("Search Region" , SearchImage)
cv2.waitKey()

#convert RGBto Lab
LabImage = cv2.cvtColor(SearchImage,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

cv2.imshow("Lab(b)" , LabImage[:, :, 1])
cv2.waitKey()

ret,Binary = cv2.threshold(LabImage[:, :, 1], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('win1', Binary)
cv2.waitKey(0)

 #find contours
 contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(Binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#create an empty image for contours
img_contours = np.zeros(target.shape)
# draw the contours on the empty image
cv2.drawContours(img_contours, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

for cnt in contours:

   x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
   aspect_ratio = float(w) / h

   area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
   x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
   rect_area = w * h
   extent = float(area) / rect_area

   hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
   hull_area = cv2.contourArea(hull)
   solidity = float(area) / hull_area

   equi_diameter = np.sqrt(4 * area / np.pi)

   (x, y), (MA, ma), Orientation = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)

   print(" Width = {}  Height = {} area = {}  aspect ration = {}  extent  = {}  
   solidity = {}   equi_diameter = {}   orientation = {}".format(  w , h , area , 
   aspect_ratio , extent , solidity , equi_diameter , Orientation))



cv2.imshow('win1', img_contours)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Width = 42  
Height = 18 
area = 632.5  
aspect ratio = 2.3333333333333335  
extent  = 0.8366402116402116  
solidity = 0.9412202380952381   
equi_diameter = 28.37823130579125   
orientation = 89.93299865722656
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Did you create the mask image where (only area where the car drives is shown) using Lab boundaries (threshold) or HSV ?. @Ziri

Comment: I created  the  mask   using lab by thresholding  and filling the holes .

Comment: Thank you. Despite the fact that the idea of working with LAB doesn't really work for me since there are other vehicles with different colors (blue) which also need to be detected (for simplification i didn't mention that in my question), you inspired me to a very intuitive but smart idea of processing only the area of trajectory. Thus i  don't need to pay attention to any other objects since no one can walk on the railroad :). @Ziri

Comment: If i may ask. How can one invest the properties resulted from your code's output taking into consideration that they are not constant for all video frames?.@Ziri

Comment: I think those parameters will be within a certain range for all video frames because the searched object doesn't change shape anyway.

Comment: that is right. However, there may also be other irrelevant objects in the binary video frames that also fall in between as i tested it, and thus we come back to the same problem. To be honest, the best idea till now is to search in the trajectory area and done. However, i thought, there might be some methods which i don't konw that could work for my case

Comment: If i may ask, which holes did you fill when you created the mask and did you threshold the image ?

Comment: Imean i can't get the same masl results as yours

Answer (score 0):

You can use approxPolyDp and calculate the approximate area of the shape and set a threshold for a range where it can be termed as the shape that you're looking for.

Comment: already tried using approxPolyDp to filter based on the shape. it is not efficient since i'm working on videos and thus it occurs that irrelevant objects have the same properties as the vehicle regarding area and ration. However, if you think i misunderstand your idea. Please don't hesitate to show me how on the above mask image. Would be thankful. @Vallabh Karanjkar